# How to start celery periodic task at 0815 and run it every 15 minutes in django

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I am trying to schedule a periodic task in Django, which would start at 0815am in the morning and run every 15 minutes. Currently it executes at 0800am first time, but I'm trying to set it so it starts 0815am.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='*/15', hour='8-23',), 
queue='xenia_celery_priority_queue_1', options={'queue': 
'xenia_celery_periodic_queue_1'})
```

As I understand, I would need to set minutes=15, so the task starts at 0815, bu I am using minutes, to run the task every 15 minutes already.

Is there a simple way to start the task at 0815 instead of starting it at 0800 and run it every 15 minutes?

Comment: ok, what's wrong?

Comment: The periodic task I posted will execute at 0800am and will run every 15minutes, so first time it will execute at 0800am. But I want to execute it at 0815am first time instead of 0800am. And I am not sure how to set it to 0815am, because I already have minute='*/15'

Comment: You can refactor the task to skip the first run... I know it sounds terrible but I can't think of any other way.

Comment: I thought about it, but will leave it as a last solution, thanks.

Comment: split your task in two-part: part one: `minute='*/15', hour='9-23'` and part two: `minute='15,30,45', hour='8'`

Comment: Hi hadi, that sounds like a solution, but what would be the right syntax for that? I don't want to write the same function twice with different periodic tasks. thanks

Comment: Apart from hadi's solution, you can put `minute='15,30,45,59', hour='8-23'` if you don't have any restrictions to run things at 59th minute instead of 00 minute

Comment: thanks @ruddra. what would happen if instead of 59 I would put 0. would it run at 8am as well then?

Comment: Probably, I can't test so can't say with 100% confidence.